# K5006-Z Mobile Broadband

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband

I have a K5006-Z Mobile Broadband USB stick from Vodafone that doesn't seem to connect when I'm using Ubuntu. I don't have access to any Windows / Macs but I did lend it to  a friend with a Mac and it worked without issue so I am confident the USB stick is working.

I have set up a Mobile Broadband connection using the Ubuntu wizard. When I plug it the stick into the laptop Network Manager allows me to select this connection. The network icon animates for a while and message appears saying "GSM Network: You are now registered on the home network". However the network icon still continues to animate and does not become stable.

During this time the lights on the stick flashes from red to green but continues to flash. After a while the connection drops with a message "Modem: Network disconnected". If I try to connect again I do not get the "GSM Network" message again unless I remove and replug the USB stick.

Any help to get this working?

Comment: As i know, the K5006Z should work with Windows and Mac OS, but not sure about Ubuntu. I think the [Vodafone K5006Z](http://www.4gltemall.com/vodafone-lte-usb-stick-k5006z.html) is not compatible well with the ubuntu system. You could ask Vodafone whether they can provide the driver for you.

Comment: Are you sure the [Vodafone K5006Z modem](http://www.4ginthebox.com/vodafone-k5006z-k5006h.html) works with Ubuntu? After checking I found that it only supports Windows and Mac OS.

Answer (score -1):

in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) use "lsusb" look for your stick listing,,at end of line in brackets you should see the installed module if not google for linux firmware to support your stick and instructions on installing  ie modprobe use,,  there is a well written trouble-shoot how-to on Ubuntu Forums also

goodluck

Comment: On inserting the USB stick lsub gives the following.

    ID 19d2:1018 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM